# Converting custom class to object and back

Tags: c#, linq, ms-access

I m trying to write a function as generically as possible (to create and fill a DB table).

My problem is that I want to use it with different classes. The problem is that in order for this to be very generic I would have to pass my custom class data into the function as List of object and then convert back.

Here is what I have:

```
public static void appenddatatotableRef(string connectionstring, string tablename, List<Object> values, string objecttype)
    {
        var properties = new List<System.Reflection.FieldInfo>();

        if (objecttype == "PowerResults")
        {
            var data = values.OfType<PowRes>().ToList();
            properties = typeof(PowRes).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
        }

        string columnam = "[" + properties[0].Name + "]";
        string valstring = "@" + properties[0].Name;

        for (int i = 1; i < properties.Count; i++)
        {
            columnam = columnam + ", [" + properties[i].Name + "]";
            valstring = valstring + ", @" + properties[i].Name;
        }


        string commandtext = "INSERT INTO [" + tablename + "](" + columnam + ")" + "VALUES(" + valstring + ")";

        using (var myconn = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            myconn.Open();
            using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand())
            {

                foreach (var item in values)
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = commandtext;
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    for (int i = 1; i < properties.Count; i++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + properties[i].Name, properties[i].GetValue(item));
                        }
                        catch
                        {

                        }
                    }

                    cmd.Connection = myconn;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
            }
            myconn.Close();
        }

    }
```

This works fine if I change the input to `List<PowerRes>` and get rid of the conversion from values to data but then it is not generic any more.

Can I make this completely generic somehow?

Working solution (thanks guys for pointing me in the right direction)!

```
public static void appenddatatotableRef<T>(string connectionstring, string tablename, IEnumerable<T> values)
    {

        var properties = typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();

        //setting up the command text for insert into
        string columnam = "[" + properties[0].Name + "]";
        string valstring = "@" + properties[0].Name;
        for (int i = 1; i < properties.Count; i++)
        {
            columnam = columnam + ", [" + properties[i].Name + "]";
            valstring = valstring + ", @" + properties[i].Name;
        }
        string commandtext = "INSERT INTO [" + tablename + "](" + columnam + ")" + "VALUES(" + valstring + ")";


        using (var myconn = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            myconn.Open();
            using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand())
            {

                foreach (var item in values)
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = commandtext;
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < properties.Count; i++)
                    {
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + properties[i].Name, properties[i].GetValue(item) ?? "");
                    }

                    cmd.Connection = myconn;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
            }
            myconn.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Public member names should be UpperCamelCase.

Comment: BTW< I wrote cleaner code that does this; see https://github.com/SLaks/ExcelExporter/blob/master/ExcelExporter/Exporters/SheetBase.cs#L26-L62 and https://github.com/SLaks/ExcelExporter/blob/master/ExcelExporter/Exporters/TypedSheet.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a generic function:

```
public static void AppendToTable<T>(..., IEnumerable<T> items, ...) {
    var properties = typeof(T).GetFields();
```

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: so if I pass my class list as "items" it wont care about the type any longer?

Comment: It will infer the generic type parameter to be the compile-time type of the list you pass.

Answer (score 1):

That can be done. Some existing open sources libraries called "MicroORMs" can do that pretty well.

Have a look on [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) for examples.

Comment: thanks. this solves the issue of getting the job done but doesnt really help my understanding and I m still a learner and want to improve... but thank you

Comment: It's my pleasure to share libraries I like. According to the code you posted, you're definitely on the right track. The missing link to achieve what you are trying is in SLasks answer and the .NET generic use. The best way to understand how Generics are working is to study some code, for example, in the links SLaks posted as comments.